# Lifting Abelian Varieties to p-adic fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties

Assume I have an abelian variety $A$ over a finite field $k$ of characteristic $p$.  Work of Norman and Oort (1980) says I can lift $A$ to an abelian variety $\mathscr{A}$ over some characteristic zero ring $R$ with a surjective morphism $R \to k$.

In fact, we can lift $A$ to the Witt ring $W(k)$ if $A$ is ordinary (Norman-Oort) or if $A$ is an elliptic curve (lift the cubic equation defining it).

1). In general, we don't expect to lift $A$ to $W(k)$.  But can we always lift $A$ to some ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, where $K/W(k)$ is a finite extension?  (Such an extension must be totally ramified to ensure a surjection $K \to k$).

2). If not, is there data internal to $A$ that tells us about when such lifts do exist, analogous to 
$$\text{Ordinary } \implies \text{lifts to $W(k)$}?$$

Comment: Maybe I'm mis-remembering, because I don't deal with abelian varieties much, but isn't the deformation functor formally smooth, i.e. $Def_A \simeq Spf(W(k)[[x_1, \ldots, x_{g^2}]])$ even for non-ordinary ones? I think ordinary allows you to realize the isomorphism as canonically coming from the $p$-divisible group and hence gives you a special "canonical lift" to $W(k)$, but I think they always lift to $W(k)$.

Comment: Smoothness is definitely true if $k$ is algebraically closed.  I've been poking around to see if this is true in general and haven't found anything clear.

Comment: Algebraization of formal deformations is *serious*, even in the ordinary case (where it is affirmative, by an argument of Serre-Tate at the end of Messing's thesis).  Beyond dimension 1 there are many non-algebraizable formal deformations over $W(k)$. The Norman-Oort paper assumes alg. closed $k$ (due Dieudonne modules), but this can be bypassed via a deformation ring argument (giving a lift over a $p$-adic *order* with residue field $k$, not that its normalization has that residue field!). Later work of Norman & Ogus gave *obstructions*, and showed a lift always exists over $W(k)[\sqrt{p}]$.

Comment: @user76758 Thanks. Silly me. Of course the hard part would be algebraization and not the formal lift part.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "lift"? If you are looking for something functorial, this is impossible already for elliptic curves since supersingular ones have quaternionic multiplication and this never occurs in characteristic $0$...

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo You're right.  I just want a lift as abelian varieties.  The only functoriality I'm looking for should be that the actions of the Galois groups (under $G(K) \twoheadrightarrow G(k)$) on the Tate modules should be isomorphic, but this should follow immediately if a lift exists.

Comment: If $A$ has a polarization of degree prime to $p$, then $A$ lifts to $W(k)$; this is another rather general case.