# Example of abelian variety over finite field which doesn't lift

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, abelian-varieties

What is an example of an abelian variety over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ which doesn't lift to $\mathbb{Z}_p$? [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163697/lifting-abelian-varieties-to-p-adic-fields) seems to hint that they should exist, but no example is given.

Note that I want to consider just abelian varieties and not abelian varieties equipped with a polarisation.

Comment: Oort gives examples of abelian varieties over a field $k$ of characteristic $p$ that don't lift to $W(k)$.   Oort, Frans. Lifting algebraic curves, abelian varieties, and their endomorphisms to characteristic zero. Algebraic geometry, Bowdoin, 1985 (Brunswick, Maine, 1985), 165--195, Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., 46, Part 2, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1987.

Comment: @anon: Thanks for the comments. I have looked at this paper. I can't find a statement in this paper which addresses my question. Can you please be more precise? Section 12 comes closest, but I can't see any finite fields in this section.

Comment: @DanielLoughran Oort doesn't construct examples of finite fields, only over some fields of char $p>0$. This is also what anon writes.